# sorting dict values without sorted function in Python

Tags: python

I want to sort values of dictionary in list without using sort function.I tried below but its not working

```
dict1={"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}
list1=[]
for i in range(len(dict1)):
    sml=[a for a in dict1.values() if a ==min(dict1.values())]
    key1=[k for k,v in dict1.items() if v ==min(dict1.values())]
    del dict[key1]
    list1.append(sml)

print(list1)
```

Comment: May I ask why you're avoiding the sort function?

Comment: You do realize that this syntax: `var = [...]` makes `var` a list rather than an item, right?. So, in a first glance try `sml=sml[0]` and `key=key1[0]` after those lines to get the appropriate variables ---  Edit: I am moving this to an answer

Comment: Also, you mean `del dict1[key]` rather than `del dict[key]`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The OP was clear about sorting the values of the dicts and not the dicts themselves. This actually makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thanks!!! As suggested i added sml1=sml[0] but getting Indexerror,Can you please advice what is the issue                                                   dict1={"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}
list1=[]
for i in range(len(dict1)):
    sml =[a for a in dict1.values() if a ==min(dict1.values())  and a not in list1]
    key1=[k for k,v in dict1.items() if v ==min(dict1.values()) and v not in list1]
    sml1=sml[0]
    list1.append(sml1)
    print(sml1)
print(list1)

Comment: @vickey99. Please explain why you can't simply do: `list1 = sorted(dict1.values())`.

Comment: @KyrSt yes, you are right. I commented too soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is almost there. Your only mistake is that the lines

```
sml=[a for a in dict1.values() if a ==min(dict1.values())]
key1=[k for k,v in dict1.items() if v ==min(dict1.values())]
```

actually make `sml` and `key1` lists with the first one containing the smallest value as its only element and the second containing the key of the smallest value as its only element.
(The syntax `x = [....]` will make `x` a list, even if there is only one element).

So everything will be fixed by making those lines as:

```
sml=[a for a in dict1.values() if a ==min(dict1.values())][0]
key1=[k for k,v in dict1.items() if v ==min(dict1.values())][0]
```

Comment: Why not just: `sml = min(dict1.values())`? And why repeat all that nonsense again, just to get the key?

Comment: Yes to get the key and delete it from dictionary.And you are right sml = min(dict1.values()) this should also work.......i am so dumb :(

Comment: @vickey99. I have no idea why you are doing this, rather than just using `sorted`. But anyway, a better approach would be to iterate over a copy of the keys, like this: `for key in list(dict1.keys()):`.